# Xampp on multiple networks

Tags: networking, xampp, raspberry-pi3

I'll introduce you in some context to understand the problem.

I have a web server with a mysql db hosted with xampp for a personal project.
The project objective is to show cpu and gpu temps in real time on a rpi3b and log the process that is consuming most RAM on that moment.
For that purpose, I have the next config:

- 1 rpi connected through ethernet directly to the computer. This rpi is configured to show the webpage on fullscreen at startup.
- SNMP protocol enabled.
- Xampp running at pc startup.
- Speedfan running at pc startup.

The webpage gets through snmp protocol info about the processes and logs it to the db. 
The web also logs to the db the cpu/gpu temps using a log file generated by speedfan.

This config is working fine and allows to the rpi to log all the info even if I'm without internet.

The problem is that if I want to access that webpage from the smartphone, I can't because the phone is on a diferent network (remember, rpi is connected directly to the pc).

Rpi-Pc address: 192.168.1.1
LAN: 192.168.0.x

PD: Sry about my english, I hope you understand xD